# Jbutton Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Como verificar se o mouse CONTINUA sobre um botão no java?
Criei um timer que após 1.5Segs executa a tarefa de mostrar um PopUp dizendo o que o botão faz, mas ainda é executado quando se tira o mouse de cima antes de completar os 1.5.. O que me causa um problema caso o usuário apenas clique e saia rápido com o mouse... O popUp se sobrepõe a um JConfirmDialog :/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode saber quando o mouse está sobre o botão ou qualquer outro elemento com este código:

```
 button.addMouseListener (novo MouseAdapter () {
 public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e) {
    // seu código aqui (verificou que está sobre o botão)
 }
```

});

E para saber que o mouse saiu e executar algo quando identificar isso, pode usar o evento:

```
mouseExited()
```

Comment: Não consegui implementar esse código... Poderia me dar um exemplo usando botão com nome btadicionar... Caso o mouse esteja em cima (entered) execute um system.out.print("sucesso")